# Error "all arguments must have the same length" con funcion strata

Tags: r

al querer hacer una seleccion de casos para un muestreo estratificado tengo un error vinculada con el tamaño de las variables.

La funcion que quiero correr:

```
s<-strata(base,c("base$propNBI2") ,size= c(72,4,0),method = "srswor")
```

Este es el error que me tira:

> Error in strata(base, c("propNBI2"), size = c(72, 4, 0), method = "srswor") : all arguments must be the same length

Estuve investigando bastante pero no logro encontrar a que puede ser el error.

No tego NA en la base, la unica variable como factor es propNBI2 que corresponde a la segmentacion que realizamos , "primero", "segundo" , "tercero".

gracias a todos

Comment: Por favor, agrega la salida de `str(base)` a tu pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido Eliam Romero a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Igualmente, casi seguro, el problema lo tienes aquí: `c("base$propNBI2")`, en todo caso debiera ser `c("propNBI2")`

Comment: gracias patricio! , mas abajo hice un comentario sobre lo que me paso

Answer (score 0):

Para que me funcionara la función tuve que incorporar `sampling` adelante, quedando así la misma:

```
s<-sampling:::strata(base,c("base$propNBI2") ,size= c(72,4,0),method = "srswor")
```

Es normal esto?? la corri otras veces y nunca lo necesite.

Comment: Normalmente eso puede ocurrir si existiera  la función `strata`  pero en otro paquete y hubiera conflicto.

Answer (score 0):

2 años tarde, pero llega aclaración, tuve el mismo problema, y esto sucede cuando tenés instalado el paquete Survey, que usa una librearia llamada Survival, que también tiene una función con el mismo nombre, entonces tenes que aclarar que queres usar "strata" del paquete Sampling, por eso se agrega

sampling:::strata